# Akka Streams: How to update one field with the result of the future

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream

I have an entity passing down the akka stream and it has one field that has to be updated during one of the flows.

Let's say `case class Entity(f: Int)`

The value to update the entity is coming from the future.

```
Flow[Entity]
  .map({ entity  ⇒
    entity.copy(
      f = // get result of the future
    )
  })
```

There are several options coming to my mind.

First is to Await for the execution of the future. But in this case, I would have to provide it with its own execution context etc... How do I use the graph's execution context within a flow?

Second is passing a tuple of `(Entity, Future[Int])` to the next stage. But it would be easier to transform it into `Future[(Entity, Int)]` and then `mapAsync` it. But is there a way to transform a Tuple with Future into a Future of a Tuple within akka stream?

What would be a perfect solution to this simple problem?

Answer (score 2):

How about something like:

```
Flow[Entity]
  .mapAsync { entity =>
    createIntFuture.map { int =>
      entity.copy(f = int)
    }
  }
```

?

Comment: Map will ask me to provide an execution context

Comment: Any solution you would try would require `ExecutionContext`, `ActorMaterializer` or `ActorSystem`. It's normal. If you don't want to pass `ExecutionContext` around pick Cats Effect with FS2 instead of Akka Streams with `Future`s.

Comment: Ok, then what's the best practice to provide execution context to this map?

Comment: If you are using Akka then you have no choice but to pass implicit `ExecutionContext` either as method parameters or class constructor. It's normal that every other class in Akka-based codebase is "polluted" with implicit `ExecutionContext`. Then you just propagate it from the `main`.

Comment: Thanks, that is what I wanted to hear. It seems a little bit weird from the first look to have all these implicits in every place.

Comment: That's one of drawback of `Future`. `cats.effect.IO` or `monix.eval.Task` are better in this regard, but it's good to have some experience with `Future` and its shortcomings before moving on to other solutions, especially if you are invested in Akka.